# Como puedo invocar al metodo getProductosPorRangoPrecio

Tags: java, array, eclipse, java-ee, get

Necesito invocar al metodo getProductosPorRangoPrecio en la opcion 6 [image: para poder imprimir los productos por pantalla]

Comment: Hola @raulvillegas, bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Deberías quitar las imágenes y añadir el código directamente en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si el método devuelve un **ArrayList** de objetos **Producto**, y ademas necesita dos parámetros double que son precioInicial y precioFinal, necesitaras un objeto que guarde el devuelto del método y tus dos parametros double ya definidos:

**ArrayList**<**Producto**> productosEnRango = getProductosPorRangoPrecio(preIni,preFin);

Comment: No lo entiiendo del todo

Comment: La linea de código que te comparto muestra como debes invocar el método. Lo único que necesitas es tener ya definido preIni (el precio inicial) y el preFin (el precio final).